# Typescript - Require a parameter in the return function if the generic is not undefined in the caller

Tags: typescript, generics, conditional-operator

Using TypeScript 5.0.2

I have a function that returns an array of 3 functions, I want the purchase function to be typed correctly so that it only requires a `requirement` param if the product specified one (identified in the `products` type object).  This is the base code that I'm working with, currently both the `purchaseSoda()` and the `purchaseBeer()` methods require a `requirements` param however there is no requirements on soda so I would only expect the `purchaseBeer()` method to throw an error as there is no requirements object passed to the method.

I don't want to have to call a method that doesn't require a param like this `purchaseSoda(undefined);`

```js
type InventoryItem<Product, Restrictions = undefined> = {
  product: Product,
  restrictions: Restrictions
}

type Beverage = { sizeInOunces: number, price: number };
type Book = { title: string, price: number }
type AgeRequirement = { age: number }

type products = {
  "soda": InventoryItem<Beverage>,
  "beer": InventoryItem<Beverage, AgeRequirement>,
  "comic": InventoryItem<Book>,
  "Adult Magazine": InventoryItem<Book, AgeRequirement>
};

const getItem = <
  productName extends keyof products,
  item extends products[productName],
  product extends item["product"],
  restrictions extends item["restrictions"]
>
  (name: productName): [
    (item: product) => void,
    (restrictions: restrictions) => product,
    () => void
  ] => {

  const addItemToInventory = (item: product) => { throw new Error("omitted for stackoverflow"); }
  const cancelPurchase = () => { throw new Error("omitted for stackoverflow"); }

  const purchase = (restrictions: restrictions): product => { throw new Error("omitted for stackoverflow"); }

  return [addItemToInventory, purchase, cancelPurchase];
}

const [addSoda, purchaseSoda, cancelPurchaseSoda] = getItem("soda");
const [addBeer, purchaseBeer, cancelPurchaseBeer] = getItem("beer");

purchaseSoda();  // Shouldn't Require a Param
purchaseBeer();  // Should Error here, because the beer product has a age requirement.
purchaseBeer({ age: 21 }); // Should require a param
```

I've tried using `never`, `null` on the default assignment for the `InventoryItem`

I've converted the `getItem` and `purchase` method to a function with an override.

I've modified the return signature of `getItem` so that its

```
  (name: productName): [
    (item: product) => void,
    (() => product) |
    ((restrictions: restrictions) => product),
    () => void
  ] => {
```

I've changed the signatures of the `purchase` method to make the param optional (using '?')

```
  (name: productName): [
    (item: product) => void,
    (restrictions?: restrictions) => product,
    () => void
  ] => {

  const addItemToInventory = (item: product) => { throw new Error("omitted for stackoverflow"); }
  const cancelPurchase = () => { throw new Error("omitted for stackoverflow"); }

  const purchase = (restrictions?: restrictions): product => { throw new Error("omitted for stackoverflow"); }
```

While this now allows me to call `purchaseSoda()` with out a param, I can now also call `purchaseBeer()` with out one as well, and `purchaseBeer()` has a age requirement that needs to be passed in.  So just adding the '?' doesn't solve my problem.

I've also read through a bunch of docs.

Playing around with this for a few hours now, and I feel stuck.

Any help on this would be much appreciated, thanks for your time.

Comment: (Please consider making your type names more conventional by making them UpperCamelCase, and ideally the type parameter names would be short like `K` so they are obviously different from specific type names.)  Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/NBJoVN) meet your needs? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: I appreciate the assistance, and yes it does solve my problem, but an explanation as to what was wrong would have also helped.  At first glance looking over your approach I didn't see where things were working because your rewrite was much harder to read.  Thank you again.

Comment: My comment wasn't meant to explain, it was meant to find out if the suggestion would work for you... now that I know it does, I'll write up an answer with the explanation. Does that suffice for you?

Comment: Yes that would be greatly appreciated, Thank you for your time and effort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TypeScript doesn't automatically assume that a function parameter that accepts `undefined` can be treated as an [optional parameter](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#optional-parameters), so if you want such behavior you'll need to do some type manipulations that express that.

Your function type is equivalent to something like

```
(restrictions: R) => P
```

which will always require a `restrictions` argument even if `undefined` is assignable to `R`.

What you'd like instead is a function type where if `undefined` is in the domain of `R` then it's `(restrictions?: R) => P` (note the `?`), and otherwise it's `(restrictions: R) => P`.  There are multiple ways to write this, but here's one using a [conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html) for the whole function type:

```
type UndefIsOptional<R, P> =
    undefined extends R ?
    (restrictions?: R) => P :
    (restrictions: R) => P;
```

Now we can use this function type instead:

```
const getItem = <
    K extends keyof Products,
    I extends Products[K],
    P extends I["product"],
    R extends I["restrictions"]
>
    (name: K): [
        (item: P) => void,
        UndefIsOptional<R, P>, // this used to be (r: R) => P
        () => void
    ] => {

    const addItemToInventory = (item: P) => { throw new Error("omitted"); }
    const cancelPurchase = () => { throw new Error("omitted"); }

    // this also used to be (r: R) => P
    const purchase: UndefIsOptional<R, P> = (r?: R): P => 
      { throw new Error("omitted"); }

    return [addItemToInventory, purchase, cancelPurchase];
}
```

And now we can test it:

```
const [addSoda, purchaseSoda, cancelPurchaseSoda] = getItem("soda");    
purchaseSoda();  // okay
purchaseSoda({ age: 21 });  // error

const [addBeer, purchaseBeer, cancelPurchaseBeer] = getItem("beer");
purchaseBeer();  // error
purchaseBeer({ age: 21 }); // okay
```

Looks good.  And let's just add another type of thing where the requirement is itself optional:

```
⋯
"optionalId": InventoryItem<Book, AgeRequirement | undefined>;
⋯
```

And you'll see that both ways of calling it are acceptable:

```
const [, purchaseOpt,] = getItem("optionalId");
purchaseOpt(); // okay
purchaseOpt({ age: 21 }); // okay
```

Comment: Excellent, Thank you for the full explanation, this helps build on my typescript skill set, and I'm sure that this will help others encountering this sort of issue.